# When installing facebook_app_events - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, facebook

Error header part -

> ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:3:6: Resource and asset merger: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 6; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

I am following this guide - https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events but unfortunately I am getting a huge error. I'm trying to connect my facebook events to my application. Tell me what is wrong with my markup (I have no idea how it should look like)
How should she look?

This is what my file looks like now -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <string name="facebook_app_id"></string>
    <string name="facebook_client_token"></string>
```

Here is the path to this file - `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

I will be grateful for any help.

All error -

```
ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:3:6: Resource and asset merger: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 6; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
3
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
2
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parseInternal(PositionXmlParser.java:268)
        at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parseInternal(PositionXmlParser.java:217)
        at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:164)
        at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:96)
        at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:127)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:212)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.ValueResourceParser2.parseFile(ValueResourceParser2.java:91)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:546)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.parseFolder(ResourceSet.java:477)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.readSourceFolder(ResourceSet.java:283)
        at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:254)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.lambda$doFullTaskAction$0(MergeResources.java:308)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:302)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doTaskAction(MergeResources.java:422)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
And about 100 more lines with similar errors
```

And....

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:87: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka kg.atlas.caravan:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:94: AAPT: error: resource string/facebook_app_id (aka kg.atlas.caravan:string/facebook_app_id) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:97: AAPT: error: resource string/facebook_client_token (aka kg.atlas.caravan:string/facebook_client_token) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:101: AAPT: error: resource style/LaunchTheme (aka kg.atlas.caravan:style/LaunchTheme) not found.
ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:116: AAPT: error: resource style/NormalTheme (aka kg.atlas.caravan:style/NormalTheme) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:328: AAPT: error: resource style/com_facebook_activity_theme (aka kg.atlas.caravan:style/com_facebook_activity_theme) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:400: AAPT: error: resource bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default (aka kg.atlas.caravan:bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:405: AAPT: error: resource bool/enable_system_job_service_default (aka kg.atlas.caravan:bool/enable_system_job_service_default) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:411: AAPT: error: resource bool/enable_system_foreground_service_default (aka kg.atlas.caravan:bool/enable_system_foreground_service_default) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:472: AAPT: error: resource bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default (aka kg.atlas.caravan:bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default) not found.

     ERROR:/Users/ostapenkodaniil/vsprojects/caravann/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:497: AAPT: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka kg.atlas.caravan:integer/google_play_services_version) not found.

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
           Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

BUILD FAILED in 32s
[!] App requires Multidex support
    Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

    Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by flutter:

        android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java

cannot prompt without a terminal ui
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

And my AndroidManifest -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.caravan">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="Caravan"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

Comment: _"This is what my file looks like now"_ - that's supposed to be all of it? Then it of course can't be valid - an XML document needs exactly _one_ root element. You have two `string` elements on the top level there.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, I'm just doing this for the first time, what do I need to add to my file?

Comment: I don't know. The Facebook documentation says, "Open your /app/res/values/strings.xml file.", so there should already have been an existing file at that point, I suppose? What did that contain?

Comment: @CBroe There is no such path at all. I created the strings.xml file myself and added what you see in the question there

Comment: @CBroe God, Facebook is causing so much trouble. The documentation for the library I'm using doesn't explain this at all. And the official documentation refers specifically to the android application, and not flutter. Also, the facebook doc says to create a new app, not add a sdc to the current project

Comment: It probably simply needs to look like here, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#String - a `resources` element as root, and then the `string` elements get added in there.

Comment: @CBroe ```ERROR:D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 72313 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.```

Comment: @CBroe Sorry bro, now I'm getting this error, any idea how to fix it?